# windows batch script: Remove all non pdf files in directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script, which removes all non pdf files from a directory.
The directory name is OUTPUT/

this what i got

```
FOR /f %%f IN (.\OUTPUT) DO 
   SET fileName=%%f
    IF NOT "!fileName:~-3!"=="pdf" (
       DEL !fileName!
    )
```

Comment: You should open up a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to read its usage information, you seem to have confused standard and /F for loops!

Comment: Use a straight `for` loop and do not set any variables. Use `%%~xf` instead and you can get rid of `delayedexpansion` and the `if` parenthesis code block as it is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is simply that you're not using the correct syntax with your `for` command, there are other remarks I noted, which I decided would be better as an answer.

The most obvious one is that there is that you're setting a variable for no reason, and then having to use it with delayed expansion.

To do it as you were, it should look more like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In (Output\*) Do (
    Set "fileName=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If /I Not "!fileName:~-4!"==".pdf" (
        Del /F "!fileName!"
    )
    EndLocal
)
```

---

These entire batch files should do the same thing.

Standard for loop:

```bat
@For %%G In (Output\*)Do @If /I Not "%~xG"==".pdf" Del /F "%%G"
```

---

Using the `for /f` variant:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/A-D-S-L "Output" 2^>NUL^|FindStr /VILE ".pdf"')Do @Del /F "Output\%%G"
```

or over multiple lines, if you find it easier to read:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
    'Dir /B/A-D-S-L "Output" 2^>NUL^|FindStr /VILE ".pdf"'
) Do (
    Del /F "Output\%%G"
)
```

---

*Please remember that almost every windows cli command has built-in help, and the vast majority accept the **`/?`** option, e.g. **`for /?`**, **`del /?`**. Additionally you can use the **`help`** command, e.g. **`help dir`**, **`help findstr`**.*